# How to wake up Nvidia Jetson TX2 from suspend mode?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

Every time I put it in suspend, I have to restart it. I tried clicking keyboard and mouse buttons, but no luck.

I also tried pressing reset, power and recovery button on the device. Power just restarts the device instead of recovering from the suspended state.

Please help.